# Проблемы с фильтром для jList

Tags: java, sqlite, swing, list

Пытаюсь создать фильтр для `jList` в котором присутствуют элементы из базы данных `SQLite` в своих попытках и не без помощи гугла продвинулся на половину. Удалось найти метод который убирает из списка лишние слова, но когда я удаляю из `jTextField` всё что я в него ввел, то прежний список не возвращается, а те слова которые остались дублируются. И я догадываюсь почему так происходит, и возможно этот метод можно заставить работать в обратном направлении. Я уже много чего перепробовал, и только это дало хоть какой-то результат.
Внес правки согласно вашему совету, и выдает ошибку в `find`.

```
package frmt;


import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;




public class Frmt extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public Connection c=null;
    public DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
     PreparedStatement pst;
     public String k;
     private static List<String> lt ;

   public void LoadList(){   

   // Запись из бд SQLite в Combobox
            try{
    String d = "Wrd";
    String qury = "Select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' ;";
     pst = c.prepareStatement(qury);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){

        dcb.addElement(rs.getString("name")) ;

    }
    jComboBox1.setModel(dcb);
    DLm(d);
    } catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }


 // Выбор элемента из Combobox
  jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {
          String sa = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
          DLm(sa);

       }});
   }


   public void DLm(String sa){
     // Запись в jList  
     k=sa;
     System.out.println(k);
                try{
    String qry = "Select * from '"+sa+"' ;";
    pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
     //dlm.addElement(rs.getString("word"));
     lt.add(rs.getString(sa));
    }
   // jList1.setModel(dlm);
    pst.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                           DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
                            jList1.setModel(dlm);
                            dlm.find(jTextField1.getText());
                        }
                    });

// Читаем jList в jTextArea
 jList1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e ->{
        String std = jList1.getSelectedValue();
       try {
            Statement st = c.createStatement();
            String qry = "Select id, word, meaning from '"+sa+"' where word = '"+std+"' ;";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
            while (rs.next()){
                int i = rs.getInt(1);
                String is = String.valueOf(i);
                String w = rs.getString(2);
                String s = rs.getString(3);
                jTextArea1.setText(s);
                jTextField1.setText(w);
                jLabel1.setText(sa);
            }   } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Frmt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 


 });

   }
   class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {



        public MyListModel(String... strings) {
            lt = Arrays.asList(strings);
            fillList(lt);
        }

        public void find(String text) {
            List<String> search = new ArrayList<>();
            if ("".equals(text)) {
                search = lt;
            } else {
                search.removeAll(search);
                for (String s : lt) {
                    if (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains(text.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        search.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            fillList(search);
        }

        private void fillList(List<String> list) {
            removeAllElements();
            for (String s : list) {
                addElement(s);
            }
            fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
        }
    }
    public Frmt() {
        initComponents();

        try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Words.db");
        System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
        LoadList();

    }
```

UPD: Код вставляет в запрос слово из колонки.

```
public class Frmt extends javax.swing.JFrame {



    public Connection c=null;
    public DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
     PreparedStatement pst;
     public String k;
     public String sm;
     private static List<String> lt ;
     private MyListModel dlm;

   public void LoadList(){   

   // Запись из бд SQLite в Combobox
            try{
    String d = "Wrd";
    String qury = "Select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table' ;";
     pst = c.prepareStatement(qury);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){

        dcb.addElement(rs.getString("name")) ;

    }
    jComboBox1.setModel(dcb);
    DLm(d);
    } catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }


 // Выбор элемента из Combobox
  jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {
          String sa = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
          DLm(sa);

       }});
   }


   public void DLm(String sa){
     // Запись в jList  
     k=sa;
     System.out.println(k);
                try{
    String qry = "Select word from '"+sa+"' ;";
    pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
     MyListModel dlm=new MyListModel(lt);
    while(rs.next()){
     String st = (rs.getString("word"));
     sm=st;
     lt.add(rs.getString(st));
    }
    jList1.setModel(dlm);
    dlm.find(sm);
    pst.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    dlm.find(jTextField1.getText());
                }
            });

// Читаем jList в jTextArea
 jList1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e ->{
        String std = jList1.getSelectedValue();
       try {
            Statement st = c.createStatement();
            String qry = "Select id, word, meaning from '"+sa+"' where word = '"+std+"' ;";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
            while (rs.next()){
                int i = rs.getInt(1);
                String is = String.valueOf(i);
                String w = rs.getString(2);
                String s = rs.getString(3);
                //jTextArea1.setText(s);
                jTextField1.setText(w);
                jTextPane1.setText(s);
                jLabel1.setText(sa);
            }   } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Frmt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 


 });

   }

    class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel<String>{
           private List<String> h;
           //Требует создать конструктор.
       private MyListModel(List<String> lt) {
           h=lt;
        }

        private MyListModel(String... strings) {

           h = Arrays.asList(strings);
                fillList(lt);
        }





        public void find(String text) {
                List<String> search = new ArrayList<>();
                if ("".equals(text)) {
                    search = lt;
                } else {
                    search.removeAll(search);
                    for (String s : lt) {
                        if (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains(text.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            search.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }

                fillList(search);
            }
 private void fillList(List<String> list) {
                removeAllElements();
                for (String s : list) {
                    addElement(s);
                }
                fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Накидал пример с фильтрацией списка:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;

    public class JListExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                    JList list = new JList();
                    MyListModel myListModel = new MyListModel("Peter", "Mike", "Gary");
                    list.setModel(myListModel);
                    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                            myListModel.find(textField.getText());
                        }
                    });
                    panel.add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    panel.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.add(panel);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setSize(300, 400);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {

        private List<String> original;

        public MyListModel(String... strings) {
            original = Arrays.asList(strings);
            fillList(original);
        }

        public void find(String text) {
            List<String> search = new ArrayList<>();
            if ("".equals(text)) {
                search = original;
            } else {
                search.removeAll(search);
                for (String s : original) {
                    if (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains(text.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                        search.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }

            fillList(search);
        }

        private void fillList(List<String> list) {
            removeAllElements();
            for (String s : list) {
                addElement(s);
            }
            fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
        }
    }
```

Чтоб Вам брать данные из БД, достаточно загрузить их в список original.

UPD:
В приведенном Вами коде, ошибка в приведении Вашей модели к модели по умолчанию и именно из-за этого метод find не находится, так как его нет в стандартной модели:

```
    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
            jList1.setModel(dlm);
            dlm.find(jTextField1.getText());
        }
    });
```

у Вас должно быть как то так, но это тоже не правильно, так как метод find сам реализует механизм обновления списка и каждый раз не нужно устанавливать новую модель:

```
    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            MyListModel dlm = new MyListModel();
            jList1.setModel(dlm);
            dlm.find(jTextField1.getText());
        }
    });
```

Откорректировал Ваш код, указав места использовлания модели:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;


    public class Frmt extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        public Connection c = null;
        public DefaultComboBoxModel dcb = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        PreparedStatement pst;
        public String k;
        private static List<String> lt;
        private MyListModel myListModel;

        public void LoadList() {
            // Запись из бд SQLite в Combobox
            try {
                String d = "Wrd";
                String qury = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' ;";
                pst = c.prepareStatement(qury);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    dcb.addElement(rs.getString("name"));
                }
                /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
                //Здесь происходит наполнение модели списка
                myListModel = new MyListModel(/*Наполнение модели*/);
                jList1.setModel(myListModel);
                /*--------------------------------------------------------*/
                jComboBox1.setModel(dcb);
                DLm(d);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            // Выбор элемента из Combobox
            jComboBox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ie) {
                    String sa = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                    //здесь только отображаете найденное
                    myListModel.find(sa);
                }
            });
        }

        public void DLm(String sa) {
            // Запись в jList
            k = sa;
            System.out.println(k);
            try {
                String qry = "Select * from '" + sa + "' ;";
                pst = c.prepareStatement(qry);
                ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    //dlm.addElement(rs.getString("word"));
                    lt.add(rs.getString(sa));
                }
                // jList1.setModel(dlm);
                pst.close();
                rs.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
                    jList1.setModel(dlm);
                    dlm.find(jTextField1.getText());
                }
            });

    // Читаем jList в jTextArea
            jList1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e -> {
                String std = jList1.getSelectedValue();
                try {
                    Statement st = c.createStatement();
                    String qry = "Select id, word, meaning from '" + sa + "' where word = '" + std + "' ;";
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        int i = rs.getInt(1);
                        String is = String.valueOf(i);
                        String w = rs.getString(2);
                        String s = rs.getString(3);
                        jTextArea1.setText(s);
                        jTextField1.setText(w);
                        jLabel1.setText(sa);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Frmt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            });
        }

        class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel<String> {
            public MyListModel(String... strings) {
                lt = Arrays.asList(strings);
                fillList(lt);
            }

            public void find(String text) {
                List<String> search = new ArrayList<>();
                if ("".equals(text)) {
                    search = lt;
                } else {
                    search.removeAll(search);
                    for (String s : lt) {
                        if (s.toLowerCase().trim().contains(text.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                            search.add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }

                fillList(search);
            }

            private void fillList(List<String> list) {
                removeAllElements();
                for (String s : list) {
                    addElement(s);
                }
                fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
            }
        }

        public Frmt() {
            initComponents();

            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Words.db");
                System.out.println("Connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            LoadList();

        }
    }
```

Но в нем много неправильной логики.
Посмотрите его еще раз.
Так же ознакомтись с конвенцией наименования в Java, на будущее будет полезно.

Comment: Спасибо большое но, он у меня не находит метод `find` в строке `myListModel.find(textField.getText());` Делал все как вы описали, за исключением того, что `private List<String> original;` перенес в самое начало, по другому в него ничего не записать.

Comment: Вы попробовали запустить мой пример? Он работает у Вас? Скорее всего вы реорганизовали код и теперь класс находится не в той области видимости

Comment: Да, я запускал его в Эклипсе, и там он отлично работал. Да, у меня этот класс находится не в `main`.

Comment: Добавьте свой код с этим методом, я посмотрю

Comment: Для полной картины кидаю весь свой код, кроме главного класса поскольку там ничего нет. Также мне не очень понятно, что писать перед find получается надо jList закрепить за пустым DefaultListModel? Пробовал класс `class MyListModel extends DefaultListModel<String>` кидать в `main` не помогает. Код добавил выше, в основной пост.

Comment: Забыл указать, список original у меня назвается `private static List<String> lt ;` .

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь. Вы правы, в том коде, который я вчера выложил, нет никакой логики вообще. Дело в том, что эта проблема вносит беспорядок в основной код, по этому я создал отдельный проект с формой для тестирования фильтра, из которого вчера и взял код. Но при перестановке кода, я напутал переменные. Это переменная `sa` содержит у меня перечень таблиц из которых выводится информация в `jList` в виде списка слов который надо фильтровать. Вместо неё должна быть переменная за которой закреплена колонка под названием "word". А при переключении `ComboBox` информация в `jList` меняется.

Comment: Код с вашими правками добавил в основной пост. Теперь программа берет в качестве значения слово из колонки word и вставляет его в запрос. В итоге я получаю в консоли нечто такое `java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'car'`

Comment: Эта ошибка у Вас возникает из-за неправильного запроса String qry = "Select word from '" + sa + "' ;";  Вы подставляете название таблицы, но для чего-то берете его в одинарные кавычки.